# Closed and Bounded subset of $R^{n}$

Tags: general-topology

Suppose that $K\subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$  is closed and bounded.$K=K_{1}\times...\times K_{n}$. Can we assume that $K_{i},i=1,..,n$ are also closed and bounded in order to assume that $K_{i}$ are compact in $\mathbb{R}$ and then use Tychonoff theorem that says that the product of compact spaces is compact ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clearly $K_{i}$ is bounded. For a sequence $(x_{l})_{l}\subseteq K_{i}$ such that $x_{l}\rightarrow x$. Pick fixed elements $a_{j}\in K_{j}$ for $j\ne i$, then the sequence $((a_{1},...,x_{l},...,a_{n}))_{l}\subseteq K_{1}\times\cdots\times K_{n}$ converges to $(a_{1},...,x,...,x_{n})$. Since $K_{1}\times\cdots\times K_{n}$ is closed,  then $(a_{1},...,x,...,x_{n})\in K_{1}\times\cdots\times K_{n}$, in particular, $x\in K_{i}$, so $K_{i}$ is closed.